# Repeating a numerical vector

Tags: r, for-loop, vector, rep

Suppose I have the following numerical vector

```
z = 1:3
f <-c(rep(z[1],3),rep(z[2],3),rep(z[3],3))
[1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3
```

Now suppose the following:

```
z =1:i #i is an interger
```

How do I write a function such I obtain the same output format as in the first line of code?
I tried a for-loop but did not get the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using for-loop:

```
z <- 3
vector <- c()
for (i in 1:z){
    vector <- append(vector, rep(i,z))
}
```

```
> vector
[1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3
```

Answer (score 3):

Try `rep` with `each = 3`

```
> rep(1:3, each = 3)
[1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3
```

or `kronecker`

```
> kronecker(1:3, rep(1, 3))
[1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3
```

or `replicate`

```
> c(t(replicate(3, 1:3)))
[1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3
```